# Convert Time value to Unix Timestamp with Microsecond accuracy in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have Time value like this :

```
const timeValue = new Date('2023-06-13T12:34:56.789123Z');
```

I need to convert this data to **Unix Timestamp** with Microseconds precisions, but method `Date.getTime()` only support Millisecond. What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: What about appending the microseconds to the timestamp? `\`${new Date('2023-06-13T12:34:56.789Z').getTime()}123\``

Comment: `convert this data to Unix Timestamp` for what purpose? since JS dates precision is millisecond, you'll need to describe what purpose you need microsecond precision to get a meaningful answer :p

Comment: i want to get unix time stamp of  this time data with microsecond precision, for example "1686659697578123"

Comment: @NghiHoàngĐức sure thing. May you explain why you need it?

Comment: I know what you want, I want to know why you want that **in javascript**

Comment: '2023-06-13T12:34:56.789123Z'.replace(/^(.+?\.\d{3})(\d{3})Z/, ($0, $1, $2) => +new Date($1) + $2);

Comment: @JaromandaX It's my project's requirement, Firstly I run a command line to get Data from Influxdb, and then I need to convert Time column of this record to time unix and pass these datas through Telegraf plugin to my organization's database

Comment: so, you're receiving `2023-06-13T12:34:56.789123Z` ... so why convert it to a Date in the first place

Comment: I received a String, but my Plugin and Database require DateTime

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/microseconds if you are using node.

It uses `process.hrtime()` or `performance.now()` if available. You can also do this yourself by using these functions but the package already does the necessary calculations. Be aware, that both these possible functions may not be available sometimes. In these cases, the package will simply fall back to `Date.now()*1000`.

Comment: there's also the "temporal" proposal for JS - you can download a polyfill and future-proof your date code (temporal has nanosecond precision)